# hg equivalent of git notes

Tags: git, mercurial

Is there a command in mercurial, that works like git notes?

Comment: Everyday you learn something now about git :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I just heard about this functionality and hoped something similar is in mercurial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I know of: I do not think Hg has yet a special kind of object to associate to commit message.

Introduced in [July 2007](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/7/15/251690), "[`git notes`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html)" by Johannes Schindelin, notes are:

> Commit notes are blobs which are shown together with the commit message.
>   These blobs are taken from the notes ref, which you can configure by the config variable `core.notesRef`, which in turn can be overridden by the environment variable `GIT_NOTES_REF`.
>
> The notes ref is a branch which contains trees much like the loose object trees in `.git/objects/`.  In other words, to get at the commit notes for a given SHA-1, take the first two hex characters as directory name, and the remaining 38 hex characters as base name, and look that up in the notes ref.
>
> The rationale for putting this information into a ref is this:
>   we want to be able to fetch and possibly union-merge the notes, maybe even look at the date when a note was introduced, and we want to store them efficiently together with the other objects.

"`git notes`" is still evolving [right now (February 2010)](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/139836).

Comment: Thanks. I guess, I have to make a feature request then :-) If only it is congruent with mercurial philosophy :-)